# mixing c and c++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have couple of questions that about mixing code:

1. a complete project based on c, if I wanna use a c++ library, then I create a wrapper around it with pure c code,then build that shared library, do I have to change to g++ instead of gcc compiler?
2. what if the wrapper compile as static library with the library?

Comment: A C wrapper around C++? What a pleasing twist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This can happen frequently.  You may write a library in C++, but want it to be usable by a C program.

Comment: Good Read: [Mixing C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

Comment: @Oli: I never want anything to be usable by a C program ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "want" -> "need" ...

Comment: @Oli: "not want" -> carefully arranged "not need"

Comment: If you're free to compile the entire thing, then this should be fairly straight-forward. If you have to ship binaries only, then you might want to link the C++ library statically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm interested to know what library you're using that has only a C++ version, and not a pure C interface.

Regardless, Since you're going to be calling C++ code, your wrapper will be considered C++ and will need to be compiled with g++. This has to do with [name-mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), and you'll need to be able to call those functions the c++ library exposes.  You can look at them with [`readelf -s`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf).

The functions your wrapper exposes, however, will need to be marked [`extern "C"`](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1143/) so that their names are not mangled. Then you will be able to call them from your pure C application.

Static vs. Shared library shouldn't really matter here. It's just a matter of the correct symbols being generated so that linking can happen.

- [How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)